Does LVQ works with non durable queue in AMQ
We have a requirement where we need to have LVQ for a non durable queue in AMQ. We tested the same with durable queue, it works fine however it is not working with nondurable queue. I wanted to know whether this LVQ feature supported with Non durable queues or will need to tweak our code to make it work.

By "AMQ" do you mean ActiveMQ Artemis? If so, which version are you using? If not, please clarify what "AMQ" means. Thanks!

What exactly isn't working with non-durable messages and how are you testing?
